# Ubuntu can't read 64GB SDXC

Tags: sd-card

My new 64GB SDXC UHS I cards do not appear in Gnome Disks let alone mount. On the same laptop and SD card reader, mounts fine in Windows 10 and my cameras. I have a 32GB SDHC UHS II formatted as exFAT and this mounts fine in Ubuntu.

When inserting a 64GB SDXC card in Ubuntu running `dmesg`  it returns:

```bsh
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card  
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card  
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

I have the exfat-fuse and exfat-utils packages installed (hence it can read the 32GB UHS II card formatted as exFAT.

Comment: Try booting from a life CD/USB and see if they mount.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, hadn't thought to try that. Unfortunately, the 18.04 Live USB behaves just like my regular installation; doesn't mount, same dmesg error.

Comment: A quick update, I got my hands on a USB SD card reader, and Ubuntu cloud read the 64GB SDXC cards fine. Strange how Windows could and Ubuntu couldn't read the SDXC card using the laptop's internal SD card reader.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810416 Confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue trying to read a Sony SDXC I 64GB card via the built-in 7-in-1 card reader (Realtek RTS5129 controller) on my desktop with exFAT support installed.  I am currently running Ubuntu 19.04.  As a workaround, I found that the card would read fine using a USB card reader (Insignia USB 3.0 Compact Memory Card Reader).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the type of Micro SD you are using. If your PC or laptop has a Micro SD or Regular SD use a Micro SD to SD adapter and try that. If that doesn't work try a different Micro SD card. IF you don't have a different Micro SD use a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify these are two brand new regular SD cards, not micro SD, and they've been purchased from reputable sources (not Amazon marketplace). I've filled them with 2½ hours of 4K footage, and extracted them using both the same laptop in Windows, and from the camera to the laptop via USB PTP.

Comment: It could be something to do with the Ubuntu.

Comment: Error 110 means timeout.

Comment: I suggest trying another Ubuntu computer with that card. Does the card super in the "disks" as an non mounted device?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS and had the same issue. Found a solution (posted by another Ubuntu user) by installing the following package(s):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please cite the source also?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and it's one that's with a double check, but as I said in the question, I already have those packages installed, and can already handle exFAT SD cards.